# limiting request with asyncio.Semaphore on blocking work with thread

Tags: multithreading, python-requests, python-asyncio, semaphore

I am using this code to make requests across different Thread.
In the main function I pass an `ark` list in producer/consumer workflow.

`_producer` makes requests with different Thread through `getRecord` which is a **blocking function** since this function is **based on the request library**. `getRecord` comes from a very specific package to make queries on a data warehouse and I don't want to rewrite it, that's why I use this workaround to make my queries on different Threads.

I have yet to implement some functions in the `_consumer`.

It seems that this code works well if you have any suggestions I am listening to you too..

but I would like to implement a `Semaphore` which would **limit the number of requests for all the Threads** andI don't know how to proceed, do you have any advice?

### BLOCKING WORK

```py
def getRecord(self,ark, granularity:[str,dict]='oai_dc'):
        prefix, client = self._client(granularity)
        try:
            record = client.getRecord() # use requests library(blocking)
            return record 
        except Exception as errors:
            print(errors)
```

### MAIN FUNCTION

```py
    async def pullRecords(self,*arks,granularity:[str,dict]='oai_dc', workers=16):
        
        #[set Queue]
        queue = asyncio.Queue()

        #[request with Tread]
        async def _producer(self):

            loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as pool:

                #[Using thread pool executors with the asyncio event loop]
                pending =[loop.run_in_executor(pool,partial(self.getRecord,ark,granularity)) for ark in arks]
                batch = []
                
                #[We loop while we have items in the pending set and call wait with that set on each iteration]
                while pending:
                    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(pending,return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED,timeout=10)
                    
                    #[adding result in batch] 
                    batch.extend([task.result() for task in done])
                    
                    #[delegate/adding result to queue when we have more than 200 result]
                    if len(batch) > 200:
                        queue.put_nowait(batch)
                        batch = []

                #[adding leftovers to batch]
                queue.put_nowait(batch)

        async def _consumer(self):
            while True:
                records = await queue.get()
                """
                I will add function for this consumer 
                """
                queue.task_done()
                
        #[fire up the both producers and consumers]
        pulls = [asyncio.create_task(_producer(self))]
        dumps = [asyncio.create_task(_consumer(self))]
        
        #[wait for the producers to finish]
        await asyncio.gather(*pulls)
        await queue.join()
```